# How to use Regex \A?

Tags: regex, pattern-matching

```
   4.6.5.7 - - [date]
```

If I do `\A4` for the above string I can get 4,
but if I do `\Adate`, I could not get a match. I probably misread the regex docs. Anybody can help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to be very specific and look for that particular string in square brackets, just use '\[date\]'.

If your query was more general, as the other posters have mentioned \A means 'start of string' rather than 'start of word'.

(This is a good site to test out different regex commands with instant feedback: http://rubular.com/)

Answer (score 1):

`\A` only matches at the start of the string, hence it works for `4`, but not for `date`.

See the [regular-expressions.info reference](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

If you wan't to match "whole words" like 4 or date use a 'word boundary' indicator instead.

```
\bdate
```

Answer (score 0):

One line, one class. The only tricky is to remember the regex \A, which matches the beginning of input. This effectively tells Scanner to tokenize the entire stream, from beginning to next beginning.